# Disable/Enable Spring boot bean validation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation

I'm looking for an easy way to enable/disable Bean validation with spring boot (using hibernate-validator 5.4.1). I'm talking about the validation of @ConfigurationProperties (that maps properties to configuration bean).

I would like to keep the binding but disable the validation (or at least disable the throw of exception).

Is there a property that I missed to disable the validation?

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question - why do you want to disable validation?

Comment: Validation will be very tight and for some test and different application out of classical usage I need to be able to disable it.